# Custom participant fields not showing for anonymous users on event registration page

Tags: civievent, profile, custom-fields

If I include custom (participant) fields in a profile on online event registration, these fields are not visible to logged-out visitors. If I visit the event registration page as admin I can see the custom fields.

I tried to reproduce this on the demo site, but could not.

Is there some permission that I am missing on my custom fields in order to have them appear on the event registration page for anonymous visitors?

[civicrm-4.6.9, Drupal 7]

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by granting the Drupal permission "CiviCRM access all custom data" to the anonymous user role as per the documentation at the bottom of this page: http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/events/creating-an-event/

Note: this is a really freaky label on this permission. I find it very difficult to tick a box for anonymous users to "Access all custom data". What?

Comment: Glad to hear you found the issue. Can you suggest a better label for it. I think that this permission being a requirement for users to submit all but the most basic forms is fairly well documented.

Comment: "Use all custom fields" or "Access custom fields in forms"

Comment: Thought it might be something like this when I read the title. It's annoying when you do something like Contact.get and don't get all the information back.